# how can I hide ShareThis icons from teasers

Tags: 7, nodes, social-network

I installed the [ShareThis](https://www.drupal.org/project/sharethis) module which works great for me, except I would like to hide the share icons from appearing in teasers. How can I do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Go to content type's manage display section and select `Teaser` tab on top right. There you can change the `display settings` of the `teaser`.